# ImageMagick 7.0.4 / NodeJS 6.9.2 / GPLGS 9.15 / Win 7: Failing to convert files

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, ghostscript

**Problem**

I am able to do a conversion from PDF to another image format from the command-line using the `convert.exe` ImageMagick command. However, when running the following JS in Node I get the error that follows the code below.

**JavaScript**

```
fs = require('fs');

var PDFImage = require("pdf-image").PDFImage;

console.log("Start");

var pdfImage = new PDFImage('test.pdf');
pdfImage.convertPage(0).then(function (imagePath) {
  // 0-th page (first page) of the slide.pdf is available as slide-0.png 
  console.log('Converted');
  fs.existsSync('test-0.png') // => true 
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "pdftester",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "PDF Tester",
  "main": "PDFTester.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "John Doe",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.1.4",
    "imagemagick": "^0.1.3",
    "pdf-image": "^1.1.0",
    "pdftotextjs": "^0.4.0"
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
Start
{ message: 'Failed to convert page to image',
  error: 
   { Error: Command failed: convert 'test.pdf[0]' 'test-0.png'
   convert: unable to open image ''test.pdf[0]'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2691.
   convert: unable to open module file 'C:\ImageMagick-7.0.4-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_PDF[0]'_.dll': No such file or directory @ warning/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/680.
   convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PDF[0]'' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
   convert: no images defined `'test-0.png'' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3254.

       at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
       at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
       at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
     killed: false,
     code: 1,
     signal: null,
     cmd: 'convert \'test.pdf[0]\' \'test-0.png\'' },
  stdout: '',
  stderr: 'convert: unable to open image \'\'test.pdf[0]\'\': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2691.\r\nconvert: unable to open module file \'C:\\ImageMagick-7.0.4-Q16\\modules\\coders\\IM_MOD_RL_PDF[0]\'_.dll\': No such file or directory @ warning/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/680.\r\nconvert: no decode delegate for this image format `PDF[0]\'\' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.\r\nconvert: no images defined `\'test-0.png\'\' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3254.\r\n' }
```

**Analysis**

The offending line is the command-line built for `convert.exe`, that is:

```
'convert \'test.pdf[0]\' \'test-0.png\''
```

What is adding the extra slashes, ticks ('), and '[0]'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your question , extra slashes denotes to enter in folder. 
you have to put your file with respect to server file from where it starts. or put your pdf file into from where  your running your apps.

Comment: I think not. The slashes look like 'escapes' to me, to preserve the quote characters. The quotes are probably present in case the filenames have spaces in them. Notice the same slashes in the package.json code , in front of the double quotes.

Comment: define your path wtih respect to server (from where you are running your server ) like this .'/tmp/slide.pdf'

Comment: I think you are missing the point, they aren't directory separators, they are escape characters meaning 'treat the next character literally'. The poster's problem is (he says) that something is **adding** the \ character into the command line. His own code has no directory separators at all. Though I do wonder if the problem is that the current working directory is different when the program executes.